# Wordpress Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required on line 97

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a friend who has a problem on his website under wordpress.
Wordpress did an update 10 hours ago and since, we cannot enter the website.
We aren't developpers and we don't know anything about it, and we don't know how to fix this easily. Can someone help us please ?
(Sorry for the bad english as I'm french)

When I try to get on the website, it show this :

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/u438775107/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in
>   /home/u438775107/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 97

Comment: Seems like unsuccessful update. Manually reupload files of the desired wordpress version.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the **WordPress was not updated Successfully**.

Try **the following** to fix it:

1!) Re-install WordPress Manually.
Take a backup of wp-content (from the file manager) and your database (from phpmyadmin or console if you don't have a GUI), just reinstall the core files.

2) Check homeurl and siteurl form phpmyadmin (should be in the wp_options table)

3) rename .htaccess file form root so that it is disabled untill we get the issues fixed.

5) Always user private browser to remove cache and check if the issue was solved.

It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to following steps

1)Remove the Error plugin Directory
   like:- c://wamp/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/revslider

2)Upload this backup plugin and active plugin

3)Then after solve this type of errors.